# close pop-up window using shdocvw?

Tags: vb.net, shdocvw

I used to close pop-up windows in VBA using the following code:

```
    Dim k As New shdocvw.ShellWindows   ' close menu window
    Dim c As WebBrowser
    For Each c In k
    If c.LocationURL = "http://specificsite.com/x.html" Then c.Quit()
    Next
```

You can see I have to check if the pop-up was opened and then close it.

I've migrated to VB.NET e2010 and it doesn't work.

I've found how to handle events and use the `NewWindow` to cancel the opening of the pop-up.

Unfortunately by cancelling instead of closing after it was opened, it causes a script error by JavaScript on the main page.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

I was working on similar kind of project that i used shdocvw you can find it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/dbadaece-a929-4246-ae34-c16d882f38d5)

You could also find this one helpful  this is using c# but you can convert it into VB Click [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/multitabwebbrowser.aspx)

Comment: Both seems to use NewWindow event wich as i said, should not be used since the 'main' page fires an jscript based upon the pop-up window giving a error message, Wich i can't make silent since IE is IE.